# What is the difference between the different *get helper* methods in Magento?

Tags: magento

I've seen several different approaches to getting a particular `helper`, and I'm hoping someone can explain the pros/cons of each approach. For example, in `template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml`, you'll see both `$this->helper('checkout')` and `Mage::helper('checkout')`. Is there a good reason for these two different methods in the same template?

Below are all the different ways of getting a helper I could find in Magento:

```
abstract class Mage_Core_Block_Abstract extends Varien_Object
{
…
    /**
     * Return block helper
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
     */
    public function getHelper($type)
    {
        return $this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton($type);
    }

    /**
     * Returns helper object
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
     */
    public function helper($name)
    {
        if ($this->getLayout()) {
            return $this->getLayout()->helper($name);
        }
        return Mage::helper($name);
    }
…
}

class Mage_Core_Model_Layout extends Varien_Simplexml_Config
{
…
    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
     */
    public function getBlockSingleton($type)
    {
        if (!isset($this->_helpers[$type])) {
            $className = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName($type);
            if (!$className) {
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $type));
            }

            $helper = new $className();
            if ($helper) {
                if ($helper instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) {
                    $helper->setLayout($this);
                }
                $this->_helpers[$type] = $helper;
            }
        }
        return $this->_helpers[$type];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve helper object
     *
     * @param   string $name
     * @return  Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
     */
    public function helper($name)
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper($name);
        if (!$helper) {
            return false;
        }
        return $helper->setLayout($this);
    }
…
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**`Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::getHelper()`**

The `Mage_Core_Model_Layout::getBlockSingleton()` method doesn't return a Magento helper object, but rather an instance of the Magento object type block.
I believe this is legacy code, such as the `Mage::getBlockSingleton()` method is deprecated.

In both cases a block instance is created from a Magento class id.

The method `getBlockSingleton()` stores the instance in the `$_helpers` property of the layout object, the method `createBlock()` will store it in the `$_blocks` property.

Only blocks from the `$_blocks` array can be referenced (and overwritten) using layout XML.

The method `getBlockSingleton()` is useful if you want an instance of a specific block class, and you want to make sure not to create a new instance of the block if it already exists.
To achieve (almost) the same effect with the instances created via `createBlock()` you would need the following code:

```
public function alternativeGetBlockSingleton($classId)
{
    foreach (Mage::app()->getLayout()->getAllBlocks() as $block)
    {
        if ($block->getType() == $classId)
        {
            return $block;
        }
    }
    return $this->createBlock($classId);
}
```

**`Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::helper()`**

The `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::helper()` method returns an instance of what in Magento is commonly referred to as a helper.
The only difference to calling `Mage::helper($name)` directly is that the layout object is set  as a property on the helper instance.

One might argue that using `$this->helper()` in template files is cleaner then `Mage::helper()`, because is reduces the number of hardcoded references (and thus the dependency) to the `Mage` class, but in case of Magento that argument is futile, because every module is very dependent on `Mage` and some of the `Mage_Core` classes anyway.

In practice there probably no functional reason to prefer one over the other, except that `Mage::helper()` is far more common and well known, It will be less confusing for other developers to read the code, which makes it more maintainable.

On the other hand, Magento is all about choice, and having many ways to accomplish a given task.

Comment: I think `Mage::helper()` is more useful, because not in every helper you need access to layout object. And anyway, you can get layout with `Mage::app()->getLayout()`. So I prefer to make less calls of methods.